# AWS Lambda function Max Memory issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am a neet in AWS Lambda, and I am writing a function that should be able to parse multiline CSV and write it as a CSV single-line. Lambda script is triggered after S3 file deposit. 
I have already written the script and it correctly worked with test files (some KBs).

```
import boto3
import botocore
import csv
import os
import sys
import datetime
import uuid

field_number = 29 

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):   
    start=datetime.datetime.now()

    for record in event['Records']:

        # get the event time
        event_time = record['eventTime']
        # get the event name (e.g. filePUT, ...)
        event_name = record['eventName']
        # get the principal_id (i.e. the user who performed the action)
        principal_id = record['userIdentity']['principalId']
        # get the name of the bucket on which event is performed
        bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        # get the name of the object affected by the action
        object_name = record['s3']['object']['key']

        destination_path='test_multiline/'+object_name.split("/")[len(object_name.split("/"))-1]

        # get the file from S3
        try:
            response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=object_name)
            print('object correctly read from S3')
    except:
            print('Error in reading file from S3')
        file_content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        file_content = file_content.replace('""','')
        file_content = file_content.replace(',\n',',""\n')
        while(',,' in file_content):
            file_content = file_content.replace(',,',',"",')

        # get the elements of the file separated by comma
        file_content_csv = csv.reader(file_content,delimiter=",")
        list=[]
        csv_line=""
        index=0
        row_num=0
        for element in file_content_csv:
            # if this condition is met, it means a new row is just started
            if len(element)==0:
                csv_line = ""
                index = 0
            else:
                # if this condition is met, it means that this is an element of 
                # the csv (not a comma)
                if(len(element)==1):
                    # check if this is the last element of the row
                    if(index==field_number-1):
                        csv_line = csv_line +""+ str(element[0].replace(',',''))
                        csv_line = csv_line.replace('\n',' ')
                        list.append(csv_line)
                        row_num = row_num+1
                    else:
                        csv_line = csv_line +""+ str(element[0].replace(',',''))+","
                        csv_line = csv_line.replace('\n',' ')
                        index = index + 1

        try:
            with open("/tmp/local_output.csv", "w+") as outfile:
                for entries in list:
                    outfile.write(entries)
                    outfile.write("\n")
            print('/tmp/local_output.csv correctly written to local')
            outfile.close()
        except IOError:
            print('Error in writing file in local')


        # upload the new file to S3
        try:
            s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/local_output.csv', 'multiline', destination_path)
            print('test_multiline/s3_output.csv correctly written to S3')
        except: 
            print('Error in writing file to S3')
    # get time lamdba function stop
    stop=datetime.datetime.now()
```

As just said, the script correctly works with file of some KBs. 
However, my file in production is around 800MB and when I upload it to S3 I got this error:

```
REPORT RequestId: e8c6103f-1287-11e9-a1cf-8fcf787319ca  Duration: 9117.51 ms    Billed Duration: 9200 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB   Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
```

As you may see I have already increased the MaxMemory to 3008MB and the execution time to 900s (the maximum one).

Then, I tried to split the 800MB file in 8 chunks of 100MB each. When I try to upload to S3 the 8 files, the computation for the first file works well, but starting from the second I got the issue highlighted above.

Can you help me to fix this issue? I was thinking that by splitting the file in smaller chunks would have fixed the issue.

Comment: Please add the complete error output. You are posting only 1 line 

`REPORT RequestId: e8c6103f-1287-11e9-a1cf-8fcf787319ca  Duration: 9117.51 ms    Billed Duration: 9200 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB   Max Memory Used: 3008 MB`. AFAIK, the max timeout can be 5 minutes for the lambda (i.e. 300 seconds),

Comment: This is all what I have in CloudWatch :
14:25:48
START RequestId: a34d076c-1287-11e9-a078-b561807c9080 Version: $LATEST

14:25:48
object correctly read from S3

14:25:57
END RequestId: a34d076c-1287-11e9-a078-b561807c9080

14:25:57
REPORT RequestId: a34d076c-1287-11e9-a078-b561807c9080 Duration: 8958.25 ms Billed Duration: 9000 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB Max Memory Used: 3008 MB

14:25:57
RequestId: a34d076c-1287-11e9-a078-b561807c9080 Process exited before completing request

Comment: @dhillonfarms actually it has been increased to 15min

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of something like SNS or SQS or even Step so that you are triggering one lambda per file instead of trying to execute all files in a single call.

lambdas were not designed for processing of large long running transactions but for processing small pieces of code that perform transaction on small pieces of data.